# Ensure finalizing iHostedServices before recycling on a IIS with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-6.0, ihostedservice

I have a dotnet 6 application with an hosted service that runs some scheduled tasks all x-minutes. So far so good, everything working almost perfectly. What I get from time to time is, that the app freezes for whatever reason and needs a restart. Well no problem, IIS has a recycling policy.
Ok, so so far I can manage everything. But, what I get is that if one of the tasks is still running and the recycling kicks in, the task doesn't finish properly.

How can I ensure, that the thread finishes before the recycling shuts down the app?

Comment: It really depends on how you dispose the resources. If your word "finalizing" actually means the .NET GC finalization then you are on the wrong track as finalizers are not ensured to be called.

Comment: You can try open a case via : https://support.microsoft.com.